# Not able to retain the height using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a blog at http://hubtank.com/. it's using the latest version of WordPress. Under the main menu I have Category (green one) I want to limit its height to `100px` and a tiny down arrow images so when anyone click on it, it will regain its original (current look) size or position also toggle.

I have tried with JavaScript but I do not have correct solutions. If I am applying it to `DIV` the category list item is not hiding or trimming. The `.` Also can it be possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#togglebutton").toggle(function() {
    $("#menu").height(100);
}, function() {
    $("#menu").height("auto");
}).click();
```

That should work: On every click, height is toggled. Runs 1st function (set height to 100px) initially by triggering click event.

It can also be animated by using

```
$("#menu").animate({
    height: "auto"
});
```

But then, the initial height should be set one time with no animation (like first example).

Answer (score 2):

yes, it's possible.

First, in your CSS for categ, you should add the two following tags:

```
height: 20px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Then add in an image with the arrow.  Let's say that it has an ID of "expand"

```
<img id="expand" src="arrow" />
```

Now add in a click event for ID expand.

```
$('#expand').click(function() {
  if ($("#categ").css("height") == "20px") {
    $("#categ").css("height", "100px");
  } else {
    $("#categ").css("height", "20px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I got your problem. Add `overflow:hidden` on your `categ` div, then you will be able to script an arrow with jQuery, like this:

```
var c = $("#categ");
if(c.height()==12){
    c.animate({
        height:50
    });
}else{
    c.animate({
        height:12
    });
}
```

I got it working here, you will just need to adjust css to your site:
http://jsbin.com/inizil

Comment: Thank you Vitor, Brian Hoover, Elektronik Lexikon, Šime Vidas! God Bless You All! Thanks for the knowledge donation!

Comment: Glad to help! Consider accepting an answer as the right one and voting up those who helped you. That's how this community works! :)